# Messed up with getElementById Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I've wrote this code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm(){
            var x = document.getElemetnById('pass1');
            var y = document.getElemetnById('pass2');
            if(x != y){
                document.write("Password Must Match");
            }else{
                document.write("match!");
            }
            return false;
       }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="pass1">123</p>
    <p id="pass2">123</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I want it if `pass1` and `pass2` is same, then it'll print out the `match` word.
What's the correct code??

Comment: Additionally, you want the `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` of the elements, not the elements themselves.

Comment: Can someone please give me the correct code?

Comment: You spelled `getElementById` as `getElemetnById` btw. You're also not calling `validateForm` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- You misspelled `getElemetnById`, that should be `getElementById`.
- You are comparing the DOM elements, not the contents of those elements.

The full working code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm(){
            var x = document.getElementById('pass1');
            var y = document.getElementById('pass2');
            if(x.innerHTML != y.innerHTML){
                document.write("Password Must Match");
            }else{
                document.write("match!");
            }
            return false;
       }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="pass1">123</p>
    <p id="pass2">123</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's a link to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/cretueyr/

Answer (score 1):

X and Y are different elements in the DOM, so `x != y` will always be true.

You want to compare the TEXT of those elements, not the elements themselves. Try checking if `x.innerText != y.innerText`.